# Objects keep colliding even though I set the groupIndex -/+

Tags: lua, coronasdk, collision

I have 4 objects of the same kind, mines, and another one that I don't want to collide with any of the other objects. I've set the `groupIndex` of the 4 objects to positive and the other object to negative. For 2 of the mines it works but with the other 2 it collides.

Here are the objects:

```
mine=display.newImage("mine.png")
mine:setReferencePoint(display.BottomLeftReferencePoint)
mine.y=-200
mine.x=math.random(0,280)
physics.addBody(mine, "static", {density=0, bounce=0, friction=0, radius=12})
mine.isVisible=true
local mineCollisionFilter = { groupIndex = 2 }

mine2=display.newImage("mine.png")
mine2:setReferencePoint(display.BottomLeftReferencePoint)
mine2.y=-400
mine2.x=math.random(0,280)
physics.addBody(mine2, "static", {density=0, bounce=0, friction=0, radius=12})
mine2.isVisible=true
local mine2CollisionFilter = { groupIndex = 3 }

mine3=display.newImage("mine.png")
mine3:setReferencePoint(display.BottomLeftReferencePoint)
mine3.y=-50
mine3.x=math.random(0,280)
physics.addBody(mine3, "static", {density=0, bounce=0, friction=0,     radius=12})
mine3.isVisible=true
local mine3CollisionFilter = { groupIndex = 4 }

mine4=display.newImage("mine.png")
mine4:setReferencePoint(display.BottomLeftReferencePoint)
mine4.y=-400
mine4.x=math.random(0,280)
physics.addBody(mine4, "static", {density=0, bounce=0, friction=0,r adius=12})
mine4.isVisible=true
local mine4CollisionFilter = { groupIndex = 5 }

function  salvareF(event)
salvare=display.newImage("RedButton.png")
salvare.x=math.random(0,300)
salvare.y=0
salvare.height=30
salvare.width=30
physics.addBody( salvare, "dynamic", {density=0, bounce=0, friction=0, radius=12} )
salvare.gravityScale=0
salvare:setLinearVelocity( 0,350 )
salvare.isVisible=true
salvare.collision=evCollision
local salvareCollisionFilter = { groupIndex=-6 }
salvare:addEventListener("collision", salvare)

end
```

Comment: You aren't using the collision filter tables you create, they should be created before `addBody` and then passed as an argument `filter=mine4CollisionFilter` just like with friction etc.

Comment: Thx, now it works just fine but another question pops comes,  why some of my object collide and some not eventho it had no filter collision?

Comment: The types of bodies static, dynamic, kinematic also have rules about collisions. Your mines will not collide with one another since that would result in two static bodies colliding. This is covered in the Corona docs.